# i want to convert the code below(neural network) from keras to pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, pytorch

i want to use pytorch instead of keras but i failed to do it my self

## Keras

```
def _model(self):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=64, input_dim=self.state_size, 
    activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(units=32, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(units=8, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation="linear"))
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001))

    return model
```

## Pytorch

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.ReLU(input_dim, 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.ReLU(64,32)
        self.fc3 = nn.Relu(32, 8)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(8, 3)
model = Model()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error? what is wrong with the conversion?

Comment: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input_dim', this is the error when running the training , the strange is that i am printing it to debug input_dim value is 10

Comment: because you need the input_dim when you call `model = Model()` so you need to provide an argument it should be `model = Model(<integer dimensions for your network>)`. When you call Model() that calls the constructor of the Model call which is `__init__(self, input_dim)`

Comment: yes thank you , this solved the problem, i want to ask you another question what is equivelent to this in pytorch in agent class   'self.model.predict(next_state)' . it says that Model object has no attribute predict

Comment: bc you don't have a function called predict in your Model class so it doesn't know what `model.predict(next_state)` means

Comment: yes i know but it was working good with keras but when i converted the NN to pytorch it doesnt seem to work , i think it is built in function  with keras

Comment: yeah keras has built in functions for predicting but here is a good tutorial that might help you get understand how pytorch works [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html)

Comment: okay thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model = Model()`

You need to provide an argument when you call `Model()` since your `__init__(self, input_dims)` requires an argument.

It should be this:

`model = Model(<integer dimensions for your network>)`